# Is there still no way to uninstall Microsoft Legacy Edge?

Tags: browser, microsoft-edge

Since Microsoft has started rolling out Chromium Edge for everyone having the versions v1803 and above via software updates, so, is there any way to uninstall the Legacy Edge in the lower versions of Windows 10. I am running on v1709 and have installed the new Edge by running the setup file. But the Legacy Edge remained as it has been.

Now I have two Edge(s) in my PC and hence trying to figure out to uninstall the Legacy Edge. The last time I tried doing it some months ago didn't  go through well and had to keep the old one. So far, I haven't been able to figure out how this is to be done. Can anyone tell me if this is even possible at all?

Comment: @John - Legacy Edge cannot be uninstalled the way you describe.

Comment: @Sanu_012 - If you asked the question here, you have to give the community more than a few hours, to answer your question.

Comment: Why are you still on 1709? It went EoL in April.

Comment: @Ramhound, I already tried that process. It doesn't work. I don't know why some people desperately want to close even a unique question :(

Comment: This isn’t a unique question.  It’s been asked a half dozen times in the last 5 years (since July 2015).  You will have to be more detailed than “it doesn’t work”

Comment: If "it doesn't work" isn't enough for you, I have already asked a question regarding the results that I obtained after trying to uninstall the old edge. It's still there and you can check it in my question profile. It's not that I have asked this question just for the sake of asking. MS have started rolling out the new edge replacing the old one. So, I thought perhaps the thing is possible now. And this question hasn't been asked after MS started replacing legacy edge with new one - @Ramhound

Comment: "this question hasn't been asked after MS started replacing legacy edge with new one" - The process does not change.  Legacy Edge cannot be removed.  How you remove it basically involves breaking the application.  That has always been the case, what you to do that, has not changed.